# UIPageViewController not push another view

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, mobile

I have a pageViewController that is called HomeViewController. Inside it I have three views called Overview, Finance and BSC.
On the third screen (BSC) I have a collectionView. How can I push to another screen according to the "didSelectItemAt" method in the collection view?

Comment: You can add PageViewController as the notification observer and post a notification when a cell of the collectionView is selected. This is one of the solution. There could be many more.

Comment: I add the notification in the home ViewController?

Comment: Emm! It's hard to say this way. You should probably add a screenshot of the structure of your screens and the code. Then I'll be able to suggest what to put where.

Comment: @Adeel thank you. This helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

My Action:

```
let notificationName = Notification.Name("bscNotification")
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificationName, object: nil, userInfo:["id":indicator!])
```

in HomeViewController (PageViewController):

```
let bscNotificationName = Notification.Name("bscNotification")
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(HomeViewController.showBSCInfo(notification:)), name: bscNotificationName, object: nil)

func showBSCInfo(notification:NSNotification){
        let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BSCInfoViewController") as! BSCInfoViewController
        vc.IdIndicador = notification.userInfo!["id"]! as! String
        vc.showBackButton = true
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```